# SQL Alter Table to Add a Column, does it do anything "scary"?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to add a column to an existing table in my live sql database.
I know how to use the ALTER command, but what I want to know is the effect this has on the table.

For example,, if using SQL Management Studio, it claims that adding a column will "drop and recreate" the table.

Will the ALTER table command do that as well?

This table is CONSTANTLY accessed and VERY important so I want to make VERY sure of this before going forward.

Comment: Take a backup of your database before modifying it.

Comment: We have backups running often, but even a backup and change within 10 minutes would lose me tens of thousands of records if things go badly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `ALTER TABLE x ADD y` will not recreate the table, it will just add the column. The only problem you can have is if the column should be `NOT NULL`. In that case, the command will end with error unless you specify a default value (if there are already rows in that table). It's because it needs to know what to fill to the existing rows.

Answer (score 5):

By "constantly accessed" do you mean "I don't have any downtime or maintenance window in which to make critical changes to the database"? If so, then *that* is the scary part. Like everyone says, this update will require an exclusive lock the table, and if it has to wait for that lock, then you may get blocking, timeouts, and possible irate users.

Too, the new column may require updating the table. I'm not 100% clear on what happens here, but if (this is a "what if" example, but it could happen) you add a char(100) column to a 10,000-row table that had just had its clustered index rebuilt with fillfactor = 0, then you are adding 100 bytes per row to pages that are already full, and where does that data go? Either you get page splits or forwarded records, both of which are going to take time for SQL to build -- meaning long blocks and further delays to access requests to the table.

Seriously, try to find downtime, or at least low-volume time (Sunday 2am?) to do work like this. And test it if you can... but very few places have testing sites that emulate seriously busy Production websites. If nothing else, a test on a copy of you DB will show roughly how long it will take, if you can get a downtime window.

Comment: Absolutely. There are times when you must have a maintenance window. You tell your users in advance that the database will be down in that time period. Of course, you test the process on a staging server first, so there are no surprises. The staging server is  set up exactly as the prod server is set up, and you do a restore from the prod backkup before tesing the process to upload a major change.

Comment: Yes, it IS scary that we don't have any good down time.  But that is what we are dealing with right now (we are TRYING to move the company to a better structure but it takes time).
Sadly there isn't any real down time as our website is accessed world wide by thousands of people every hour.

Answer (score 1):

*(Disclaimer: answer based on general SQL experience, not specific to MS SQL Server)*

Try it out first, in a less critical database.

At the very least, it's likely going to require a table lock, which will block access for the duration of the change. That might a few milliseconds to a minute or more depending on the size of the table and the server load.

An `ALTER` command that only adds a column **shouldn't** remove any existing information.

Answer (score 0):

If he do anything "scary", this may be only bug in your database server code.

But you must know, the database was locked on few time depends on database lenght, while column was adding.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the script it generates.

If you tried to insert a column in the GUI, this will rewrite the table.

Adding a column at the end will not.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how your database engine lays out files.  "Scary" behavior can be avoided if either:

1. It's possible to add a `NULL` to the end of each row without actually adding bytes to the row, or
2. Each row has sufficient room for expansion.

In [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html), for example, `ADD COLUMN` is always an O(1) operation.

MS SQL Server does not have property (1), and may require page splits if property (2) is false.